# how to get material on array objects?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to assign material to array objects in cycles , but it seems to be not working and I have no idea that what could be issue. Please help[image]

Comment: you have two materials. just delete the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two materials. just select the first one and press "-".

[image]

Comment: thank you so much @Chris

Comment: glad i could help